# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Current user principal is not of type when i try to integrate keycloak with spring boot web + spring security project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, keycloak

I Created a spring boot web project (.war) to be deployed in an application server.I want to integrate keycloak sso with spring security.The redirection to keycloak login page is working fine. But after that it is throwing error in browser.

Error which is getting thrown in browser

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Current user principal is not of type [org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal]: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@450ca8a1: Principal: da02ad1b-32c1-4dde-a6f4-b56a06d7dc2e; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@20e00226; Not granted any authorities

Error in application server console

> 2019-11-12 14:29:38.306 ERROR 6280 --- [nio-8089-exec-5] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Current user principal is not of type [org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal]: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@f4a97409: Principal: da02ad1b-32c1-4dde-a6f4-b56a06d7dc2e; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@11f292bf; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='user-premium'}, KeycloakRole{role='user'}]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current user principal is not of type [org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal]: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@f4a97409: Principal: da02ad1b-32c1-4dde-a6f4-b56a06d7dc2e; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@11f292bf; Granted Authorities: KeycloakRole{role='user-premium'}, KeycloakRole{role='user'}
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:166) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:121) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]

Answer (score 2):

> exception [Current user principal is not of type [org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal]

you should use `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` instead of `KeycloakPrincipal`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was like i used KeycloakPrincipal principal in contoller method